# Browser not caching static file

Tags: apache, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, mod-expires

I am using Apache server with mod_expires enabled. I have setup headers so that static files expire a week later. File is request via jQuery.get() method, cache set to true.

However, when I refresh the page on browser (Firefox), it always requests the file again. Caching and header field values seem to have no effect.

Below is a screenshot from Firefox developer tools.[image: Request and response headers]

Comment: I changed Apache settings so that response header has `cache-control: max-age=604800, public`. Still, no effect on caching. File is served everytime in full.

Answer (score 0):

How did you come up with the `If-None-Match` value? I don't see an `ETag` header with that value. Server will always send you a new one.

Another thing note is browser reload behaviour. By asking a refresh you may be asking for an end to end reload which bypasses all the caches, afaik.